# Heteroscedasticity in categorical fixed factor. Is there a similar function varIdent of nlem (R) in SAS?

Tags: r, sas

I would like to know how I can implements different variances per categorical factor in Proc GLIMMIX of SAS.

I have done a generalized lineal mixed model with a beta distribution with 1 categorical fixed factor, and 3 random factors, and I got a model with heteroscedasticity along my categorical fixed factors.

Now I want to add a variance structure like "varIdent" in the package nlme of R as is recommended in the book "Mixed Effects Models and Extensions in Ecology with R" Zuur et al., 2009.

Comment: +1 for making me look up "heteroscedasticity" :-)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for but it may be a start: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/66859/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_glimmix_syntax30.htm